# Image does not load in google automl cloud vision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vision, automl

I tried to create object classification and object detection model in google automl vision.

The image keeps on loading and i am unable to annotate the image even if it is a small dataset as shown in [Buffering image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSez9.png)   .

There is no network issue here,i have verified it with speed test.

Is anybody else facing this issue now???

Regards,

Aswin Kumar

Comment: Which format and how big are the images you are trying to upload? Please include any information that you think can be useful to reproduce your issue. If not it is very difficult to know what can be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small dataset I got the pictures displayed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbdd7.png

Do you think you may have rights restrictions in the Cloud Storage bucket containing the files?

I do experience JS errors though, which prevent me from saving manually drawn bounding boxes.